# How to prevent posting duplicate comments on Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have looked everywhere, here and on the web, and couldn't find the solution.

Basically, I'm trying to prevent posting duplicate comments on WordPress.

I have read somewhere that it's not that simple, and first WordPress needs to compare already posted comments.

Maybe someone has a quick and easy solution, or have done/implemented something similar on their own Wordpress blog.

Maybe a simple code for functions.php?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate comments ? You can't really prevent someone from posting 2 times the same thing really... The user could add a space or a dot and you wouldn't be abble to detect it...The closest possible thing, would be to restrict the number of comment per post per account

Comment: hey, I understand what you mean by adding a space. Right now I'm looking to prevent from posting the exact comment word by word. Restricting the number of comments per post per account won't do the job. thanks for your comment though.

Comment: Scanning through all existing comments each time a user leaves a comment will have a bad impact on the server and like @amarinediary said, anyone can and will circumvent this easily - especially spammers - it's their bread and butter after all.. If you're fighting spam, use a plugin like Akismet. If you 100% need to prevent EXACT copies, I would create a checksum table on the DB, and store crc32 or md5 for every comment. That way, you can just get the list of hashes from the DB every time someone posts a new comment and quickly search for a match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although what you ask seems reasonable, in reality it has a design flow: ensuring that every comment, ever, is unique is expensive as it depends linearly on all your comment base. This means that every time a user posts a comment, that operation will take more and more to complete.

Beside this, defeating this expensive validation is trivial and involves just adding some padding characters: suddenly, you must implement more custom checks for every comment posted, thus slowing down your site more.

The more your site slows down, the more resources (and money) and money you need. Assuming you are fighting spam, there are plugins designed for that purpose (like Akismet cited in the comments). A spam filter plugin doesn't scan all your comments, but uses more advanced techniques to evaluate different aspect of the text to be analyzed, and then decide whether or not to filter it.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I started to figure it out, that probably deleting duplicates will be more server load/money cost-efficient. Thanks.